# Can't link to SDL in XCode4!

Tags: macos, xcode4, sdl

I am thoroughly frustrated! I was trying to get acclimated with SDL tonight but I hit a brick wall trying to link to it via XCode4! Here's what I did. I downloaded v1.2.14 of the SDL framework runtime libraries and development xtras. I followed all the directions (dragging/dropping the SDL.framework in /Library/Frameworks) up to the point where I realized that templates don't work in XC4 the way they used to in XC3.x. I punted on the templates and tried to add the framework to a vanilla cocoa application. (Created from the built-in application template.) I added the SDLMain .h .m and .nib files and tried to build. Immediately I got an error saying it couldn't find "SDL.h". I manually adjusted my header search path setting for all configs though I thought this shouldn't be necessary if I referenced the framework directly. I got around the missing header file this way but started hitting linker errors.

```
"_SDL_main", referenced from:
      -[SDLMain applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in SDLMain.o
```

I've tried all different renditions of satisfying both my linker and compiler. I've moved the framework to my user folder under ~/Library/Frameworks, I've toyed with both <> and "" import syntax. I've started a completely brand new project and repeated everything. I'm lost! can somebody help?

Comment: Does your `main()` function take two parameters?

Comment: Yes it does: int main (int argc, char **argv)

Comment: Wow, I post questions and forget where or why I posted them! What was even attempting here??? Oh yes, StarControl for iOS. I read up on the source and ran off on a tangent...

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but if anyone stumbles across this now.

XCode by default creates the main function with the declaration

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

While SDL is looking for a function with the declaration

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

Note lack of const in char * argv[]. It seem that when SDL is looking for a char * [] Xcode gives it a const char * [] and that it causing it to fail to find the symbol.

I really wish SDL would stop renaming my functions! There must be a better solution, but hey, this will do for now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if your still looking for that, but I think it's because SDL is looking for a C symbol name, but your main is declared in a C++ file.

You have to do:

```
extern "C" int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
}
```

It's "documented" in SDL_main.h :

```
/** The application's main() function must be called with C linkage,
 *  and should be declared like this:
 *      @code
 *      #ifdef __cplusplus
 *      extern "C"
 *      #endif
 *  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 *  {
 *  }
 *      @endcode
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, makes complete sense, though I have yet to go back and try this again. Thanks for the tip! :)